# Searalize protobuff data to avro - Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Is it possible to serialize protobuff data to Avro and write to files using Apache Flink sink?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no out-of-the-box solution for protobuf yet. It's high on the priority list.

You can use [protobuf-over-kryo](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/custom_serializers.html) or [parse/serialize manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278826/using-protobuf-with-flink) in the meantime.

Comment: Any timeline on this?

Comment: Or any source on this? :-)

Comment: Found the related issue and PR on the Protobuf out-of-the-box support: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-11333 and https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/7598