# How should I define Flink's Schema to read Protocol Buffer data from Pulsar

Tags: scala, apache-flink, apache-pulsar, protocol-buffers

I am using [Pulsar-Flink](https://github.com/streamnative/pulsar-flink) to read data from Pulsar in Flink. I am having difficulty when the data's format is Protocol Buffer.

In the GitHub top page, Pulsar-Flink is using `SimpleStringSchema`. However, seemingly it does not comply with Protocol Buffer officially. Does anyone know how to deal with the data format? How should I define the schema?

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment see = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("topic", "test-source-topic")
FlinkPulsarSource<String> source = new FlinkPulsarSource<>(serviceUrl, adminUrl, new SimpleStringSchema(), props);

DataStream<String> stream = see.addSource(source);

// chain operations on dataStream of String and sink the output
// end method chaining

see.execute();
```

FYI, I am writing Scala code, so if your explanation is for Scala(not for Java), it is really helpful. Surely, any kind of advice is welcome!! Including Java.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278826/using-protobuf-with-flink/63175640.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement your own `DeserializationSchema`. Let's assume that you have a protobuf message Address and have generated the respective Java class. Then the schema should look like the following:

```
public class ProtoDeserializer implements DeserializationSchema<Address> {
    @Override
    public TypeInformation<Address> getProducedType() {
        return TypeInformation.of(Address.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Address deserialize(byte[] message) throws IOException {
        return Address.parseFrom(message);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEndOfStream(Address nextElement) {
        return false;
    }
}
```